# DUMP in unhandled C++ exception

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, exception

In MSVC, how can I make any unhandled C++ exception (std::runtime_error, for instance) crash my release-compiled program so that it generates a dump with the full stack from the exception throw location?

I have installed NTSD in the AeDebug registry and can generate good dumps for things like memory access violation, so the matter here comes down to crashing the program correctly, I suppose.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally cracked it down.

1. Use the `set_terminate()` function to register a handler for every thread
2. In you main function(), make it impossible for external DLLs (event Windows') to successfully call `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter()`. A great article on how to do that here: http://www.debuginfo.com/articles/debugfilters.html#overwrite .
3. As for the handle itself, it is quite straightforward:

```
void Terminate()
{
  OutputDebugStringA("Terminate\r\n");
  RaiseException(0xE0000010, EXCEPTION_NONCONTINUABLE, 0, 0);
}
```

Calling `RaiseException()` like the above example is enough to make the process crash and produce my mush desired dump.

Just so you know, the problem I was having was:

1. The IPHelper Windows API loads dynamically another Windows DLL
2. This DLL uses Windows own version of the C runtime (MSVCRT instead of MSVCRT90)
3. The new C++ runtime calls `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter()` on startup to catch C++ exceptions. Since the latest filter for C++ exceptions is the one who gets to call  the handle set by set_terminate(), my handle wasn't called.

Answer (score 1):

[`SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680634%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [`DebugBreak`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679297%28VS.85%29.aspx) should probably do the job.

Edit: oops, rereading, you want to deal with uncaught C++ exceptions. That would be a bit trickier to do well -- by the time you (normally) get wind of a C++ exception, it's already unwound the stack back to the level of the handler. You don't have any real way to know an exception has been thrown until a `catch` is invoked, but by then the stack has been unwound.

Comment: The set_terminate() function from MSCVRT should do the trick, but I can't get it to work: my handler (which calls RaiseException() and makes the program crash) is never called.

Comment: `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter` **does** work just as well for *unhandled* C++ exceptions as it does for SEH exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using the Windows Debugger.
Windbg – wraps KD and NTSD with a decent UI.
Also check out ADPlus that comes with the Windows Debugger.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/windbg_part1.aspx) is a good place to start learning how to use it.

Comment: Using the debugger is fine, but that can't be done on the unattended environment the program is running. See, this is a production environment: if there is a problem, the service crashes and will be restarted. I really need a crash dump to perform post-mortem analysis later on. 
I also need this information on the collected by Windows Error Reporting which I will get later on.

Comment: The Windows Debugger comes with a utility called ADPlus that allowed me to easily gather stack trace for a crash for a release build application. I agree this something that you should only do when trying to track down a crash, not on a continuous basis. For that you need a logging system. Check out all the command switches for ADPlus.